# Find remote bluetooth MAC address

Tags: android

How do I programmatically find the address of the device paired to my Android device?

I tried `BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);`, but it says it can't resolve symbol address.

Answer (score 1):

To find all bounded devices you should use the next code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices) {
    Log.d("Address: ", device.getAddress());
}
```

You could use your construction only if you had bluetooth addresses of paired devices, but you don't have them, so you have to get them from the system.

The word `address` you tried to use java understands as variable. You didn't define it, so there is an error

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now, but I get an address with one 2 and remaining zeroes... doesn't seem right

Comment: What device do you use? Maybe there is a problem with your phone or device you paired

Comment: Done, made a few minor changes. It's working now. Will post soon.